# Редирект с передалей данных

Tags: redirect, java, servlet

Обычно в сервлете я сохраняю сообщения:

```
request.setAttribute(“messages”, messages);
```

Затем при помощи forward перехожу на jsp страницу, где вывожу эти сообщения:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher().forward(request, response);
```

Нужно решить следующую проблему. На странице добавляется какой-то товар в корзину, нужно уйти с этой страницы на страницу со списком товаров при этом на странице со списком товаров вывести сообщение удачно ли добавляет товар или сообщения об ошибкax.
Для перехода делаю редирект:

```
response.sendRedirect(command.getRedirect());
```

Как при редиректе передать `ArrayList` с сообщениями по аналогии с первым примером.

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute() сохраняет переданные ему объекты в обычном Map-е внутри объекта request-а. Форвард происходит внутри сервлетного контейнера и снаружи (например для браузера) никак не виден. JSP-ный сервлет продолжает работу с тем же самым объектом request, http-соединением и пр., более того, это происходит в том же самом servlet thread.

Редирект - это посылка браузеру ответа с кодом HTTP 307, при получении которого браузер повторяет первоначальный запрос, но с другим URL. Для сервлетного контейнера это новый запрос, с новым объектом request, другим (в общем случае) servlet thread, и пр. Соответственно, передать объект тем же способом не получится.

Что можно сделать? Простых вариантов, собственно, всего два:

- Сохранить в сессии;
- Сериализовать и передать через параметр URL (возможно не само сообщение, а его код).

Comment: А какой из двух вариантов лучше?
И какой вообще способ считается стандартным для случая : 
1. Пользователь выполняет запрос.
2. Чтобы бы пользователь в случае обновления текущей станицы не отравил запрос заново делаем редирект на другую страницу и там выводим сообщения.

Comment: Универсального ответа я не знаю :)   Если мне нужно было бы в этой ситуации вернуть один message, к тому же статически формируемый (т.е, что-то вроде "Товар добавлен в корзину"), я бы, наверное, сделал это через URL-параметр, где передавал бы код сообщения.

Если класть что-то в сессию, то нужно помнить о том, что оно там будет лежать до конца жизни сессии, поэтому после использования его надо будет явно удалять и т.д.